# ErrorProvider - Change BackColor Instead of Showing Icon

Tags: c#, winforms, idataerrorinfo, errorprovider

I'm stuck with some legacy code that I want to upgrade a bit. I want to change the way the `ErrorProvider` shows the error status on a Control. Default behavior is the Icon, and a `ToolTip` if you hover on the icon.

I would like to change this behavior to be more similar to what we use in our WPF controls. Which is a red back-color(Salmon pink) and the tool-tip on the control itself.

Any tips, links or some way forward

EDIT. 
See my answer below, on what i ended up with.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Code now posted as an answer. Thank you again @Reza-Aghaei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ErrorProvider` component doesn't support this feature and if you need it you can create it yourself.

You can subscribe to `BindingComplete` event of a `BindingManagerBase` and then you can use the event arg which is of type `BindingCompleteEventArgs` that contains some useful properties:

- `ErrorText` to determine if there is an error in data-binding
- `Binding.Control` to determine the control which is bounded to

These are enough for us to implement our solution.

**Code**

Here is a sample code which shows how can you handle `BindingComplete` event and use it to change `BackColor` and tool-tip of a control based on it's valid or invalid state.

Suppose you have a binding source, `myBindingSource` which is bound to a `SampleModel` class which is implemented `IDataErrorInfo`. You can subscribe to `BindingComplete` event of `this.BindingContext[this.myBindingSource]`:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.myBindingSource.DataSource = new SampleModel();

    var bindingManager = this.BindingContext[this.myBindingSource];
    bindingManager.BindingComplete += bindingManager_BindingComplete;
}

Dictionary<Control, Color> Items = new Dictionary<Control, Color>();
private void bindingManager_BindingComplete(object sender, BindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    var control = e.Binding.Control;
    //Store Original BackColor
    if (!Items.ContainsKey(control))
        Items[control] = control.BackColor;

    //Check If there is an error
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.ErrorText))
    {
        control.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
        this.errorToolTip.SetToolTip(control, e.ErrorText);
    }
    else
    {
        e.Binding.Control.BackColor = Items[e.Binding.Control];
        this.errorToolTip.SetToolTip(control, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Reza Aghaei. This is what i came up with based on your comment and some additional searching... Some of this code comes from [msdn resource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ErrorProvider.cs,4f65fb54f47ac965,references)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ErrorProvider
{
    class BackgroundColorErrorProvider: Component, IExtenderProvider, ISupportInitialize
    {

        public BackgroundColorErrorProvider()
        {
            currentChanged = new EventHandler(ErrorManager_CurrentChanged);
        }
        public BackgroundColorErrorProvider(ContainerControl parentControl)
            : this()
        {
            this.parentControl = parentControl;
            propChangedEvent = new EventHandler(ParentControl_BindingContextChanged);
            parentControl.BindingContextChanged += propChangedEvent;
        }
        public BackgroundColorErrorProvider(IContainer container)
            : this()
        {
            if (container == null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
            }

            container.Add(this);
        }

        public bool CanExtend(object extendee)
        {
            return extendee is Control && !(extendee is Form) && !(extendee is ToolBar);
        }

        private bool inSetErrorManager = false;
        private object dataSource;
        private string dataMember = null;
        private ContainerControl parentControl;
        private BindingManagerBase errorManager;
        private bool initializing;
        private EventHandler currentChanged;
        private EventHandler propChangedEvent;
        private Dictionary<Control, Color> originalColor = new Dictionary<Control, Color>();
        private Color errorBackgroundColor;

        public ContainerControl ContainerControl
        {
            [UIPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Window = UIPermissionWindow.AllWindows)]
            [UIPermission(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand, Window = UIPermissionWindow.AllWindows)]
            get
            {
                return parentControl;
            }
            set
            {
                if (parentControl != value)
                {
                    if (parentControl != null)
                        parentControl.BindingContextChanged -= propChangedEvent;

                    parentControl = value;

                    if (parentControl != null)
                        parentControl.BindingContextChanged += propChangedEvent;

                    Set_ErrorManager(this.DataSource, this.DataMember, true);
                }
            }
        }

        public string DataMember
        {
            get { return dataMember; }
            set
            {
                if (value == null) value = "";
                Set_ErrorManager(this.DataSource, value, false);
            }
        }

        public object DataSource
        {
            get { return dataSource; }
            set 
            { 
                if ( parentControl != null && value != null && String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.dataMember))
                {
                    // Let's check if the datamember exists in the new data source
                    try
                    {
                        errorManager = parentControl.BindingContext[value, this.dataMember];
                    }
                    catch (ArgumentException)
                    {
                        // The data member doesn't exist in the data source, so set it to null
                        this.dataMember = "";
                    }
                }
                Set_ErrorManager(value, this.DataMember, false);
            }
        }

        public override ISite Site
        {
            set
            {
                base.Site = value;
                if (value == null)
                    return;

                IDesignerHost host = value.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost)) as IDesignerHost;
                if (host != null)
                {
                    IComponent baseComp = host.RootComponent;

                    if (baseComp is ContainerControl)
                    {
                        this.ContainerControl = (ContainerControl)baseComp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private ToolTip toolTip;

        public ToolTip ToolTip
        {
            get { return toolTip; }
            set { toolTip = value; }
        }

        public Color ErrorBackgroundColor
        {
            get { return errorBackgroundColor; }
            set { errorBackgroundColor = value; }
        }

        private void Set_ErrorManager(object newDataSource, string newDataMember, bool force)
        {
            if (inSetErrorManager)
                return;
            inSetErrorManager = true;
            try
            {
                bool dataSourceChanged = this.DataSource != newDataSource;
                bool dataMemberChanged = this.DataMember != newDataMember;

                //if nothing changed, then do not do any work
                //
                if (!dataSourceChanged && !dataMemberChanged && !force)
                {
                    return;
                }

                // set the dataSource and the dataMember
                //
                this.dataSource = newDataSource;
                this.dataMember = newDataMember;

                if (!initializing)
                {
                    UnwireEvents(errorManager);

                    // get the new errorManager
                    //
                    if (parentControl != null && this.dataSource != null && parentControl.BindingContext != null)
                    {
                        errorManager = parentControl.BindingContext[this.dataSource, this.dataMember];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        errorManager = null;
                    }

                    // wire the events
                    //
                    WireEvents(errorManager);

                    // see if there are errors at the current
                    // item in the list, w/o waiting for the position to change
                    if (errorManager != null)
                        UpdateBinding();
                }
            }
            finally
            { 
                inSetErrorManager = false;
            }
        }

        public void UpdateBinding()
        {
            ErrorManager_CurrentChanged(errorManager, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        private void UnwireEvents(BindingManagerBase listManager)
        {
            if (listManager != null)
            {
                listManager.CurrentChanged -= currentChanged;
                listManager.BindingComplete -= new BindingCompleteEventHandler(this.ErrorManager_BindingComplete);

                CurrencyManager currManager = listManager as CurrencyManager;

                if (currManager != null)
                {
                    currManager.ItemChanged -= new ItemChangedEventHandler(this.ErrorManager_ItemChanged);
                    currManager.Bindings.CollectionChanged -= new CollectionChangeEventHandler(this.ErrorManager_BindingsChanged);
                }
            }

        }

        private void WireEvents(BindingManagerBase listManager)
        {
            if (listManager != null)
            {
                listManager.CurrentChanged += currentChanged;
                listManager.BindingComplete += new BindingCompleteEventHandler(this.ErrorManager_BindingComplete);

                CurrencyManager currManager = listManager as CurrencyManager;

                if (currManager != null)
                {
                    currManager.ItemChanged += new ItemChangedEventHandler(this.ErrorManager_ItemChanged);
                    currManager.Bindings.CollectionChanged += new CollectionChangeEventHandler(this.ErrorManager_BindingsChanged);
                }
            }
        }


        private void ErrorManager_BindingsChanged(object sender, CollectionChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            ErrorManager_CurrentChanged(errorManager, e);
        }

        private void ParentControl_BindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Set_ErrorManager(this.DataSource, this.DataMember, true);
        }

        private void ErrorManager_ItemChanged(object sender, ItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            BindingsCollection errBindings = errorManager.Bindings;
            int bindingsCount = errBindings.Count;

            // If the list became empty then reset the errors
            if (e.Index == -1 && errorManager.Count == 0)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < bindingsCount; j++)
                {
                    if ((errBindings[j].Control != null))
                    {
                        // ...ignore everything but bindings to Controls
                        SetError(errBindings[j].Control, "");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ErrorManager_CurrentChanged(sender, e);
            }
        }

        private void SetError(Control control, string p)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(p))
            {
                if (originalColor.ContainsKey(control))
                    control.BackColor = originalColor[control];
                toolTip.SetToolTip(control, null);
            }
            else
            {
                control.BackColor = ErrorBackgroundColor;
                toolTip.SetToolTip(control, p);
            }
        }

        private void ErrorManager_BindingComplete(object sender, BindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            Binding binding = e.Binding;

            if (binding != null && binding.Control != null)
            {
                SetError(binding.Control, (e.ErrorText == null ? String.Empty : e.ErrorText));
            }
        }

        private void ErrorManager_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (errorManager.Count == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            object value = errorManager.Current;
            if (!(value is IDataErrorInfo))
            {
                return;
            }

            BindingsCollection errBindings = errorManager.Bindings;
            int bindingsCount = errBindings.Count;

            // We can only show one error per control, so we will build up a string...
            //
            Hashtable controlError = new Hashtable(bindingsCount);

            for (int j = 0; j < bindingsCount; j++)
            {

                // Ignore everything but bindings to Controls
                if (errBindings[j].Control == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                string error = ((IDataErrorInfo)value)[errBindings[j].BindingMemberInfo.BindingField];

                if (error == null)
                {
                    error = "";
                }

                string outputError = "";

                if (controlError.Contains(errBindings[j].Control))
                    outputError = (string)controlError[errBindings[j].Control];

                // VSWhidbey 106890: Utilize the error string without including the field name.
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(outputError))
                {
                    outputError = error;
                }
                else
                {
                    outputError = string.Concat(outputError, "\r\n", error);
                }

                controlError[errBindings[j].Control] = outputError;
            }

            IEnumerator enumerator = controlError.GetEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                DictionaryEntry entry = (DictionaryEntry)enumerator.Current;
                SetError((Control)entry.Key, (string)entry.Value);
            }
        }


        public void BeginInit()
        {
            initializing = true;
        }

        public void EndInit()
        {
            initializing = false;
            Set_ErrorManager(this.DataSource, this.DataMember, true);
        }
    }
}
```