# How to change an ErrorProvider's Tooltip Font

Tags: c#, winforms

I am in need of a control that displays an error icon next to a textbox when I check its contents and I deem the content invalid. Idealy with a tooltip.

The [`ErrorProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx) component does exactly what I want. However, the text size of the tooltip seems to be fixed to 8.

For a normal tooltip you have to make use of `OwnerDraw`, this property and related events seem to be missing from `ErrorProvider`. Is there another way to do this? Or acces the inner tooltip?

Setting the systems tooltip setting works for every other tooltip, except for the `ErrorProvider` tooltips.

Comment: You need to create your own ErrorProvider if you need such feature. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35960312).

Comment: It is a system setting, modifying it changes tool tips in every program.  You cannot change your user's preference, nor should you.

Comment: @HansPassant Thankfully this is an HMI setting, the PC's only purpose is running the app. Does this system setting change more then just label font?

Comment: @HansPassant Just tried setting the windows tooltip size, for fun to the maximum of 24. Every tooltip changed, except the one for `ErrorProvider`.